# Magento 2 Magento\Catalog\Model\layer getProductCollection() not effecting filters

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, layered-navigation

I'm trying to update my catalog and catalogsearch listing collection in `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer::getProductCollection()`. I need to show only grouped product in my list.

First of all, when I tried to overide `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer` in my custom module, it is not working.

So, I wrote my code directly in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php`. The collection is only working in `list.phtml` but does not work in layer navigation filter.

Can anybody please let me know how to overide catalog and catalogsearch listing collection in Magento 2?

```php
public function getProductCollection()
{
    if (isset($this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()])) {
        $collection = $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()];
    } else {
        $collection = $this->collectionProvider->getCollection($this->getCurrentCategory());
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
        $this->prepareProductCollection($collection);
        $this->_productCollections[$this->getCurrentCategory()->getId()] = $collection;
    }
    return $collection;
}
```

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: @navin did you get solution ? I am facing same problem